# Horizontal scrollbar appears in almost all apps when i resize the app in windows 11 pro

Tags: scrollbar, responsive, windows-11

I have recently installed windows 11 pro and one thing that annoys me is that non of the app are responsive in smaller width. A horizontal scrollbar appears (which i think must not as these apps work fine and adapt responsively to the changing width)

I am facing this issue in almost all the desktop apps such as chrome, edge, file explorer, and some other windows apps (at it is very annoying)

[image: image showing non responsiveness]

I tried to adjust my resolution and scale but it had no effect.

What i think (either it is a bug that i don't know how to solve or its my screen resolution and scale that is causing the apps to behave in this way)

This is my device

```
Dell Latitude 14 7490 - 8th Gen Core i7
```

and i am using both this and windows 11 for first time.